# New laptop screen is 1920 x 1080 no option for this res still using native res 1366 * 768

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, resolution, intel-graphics

As the title suggests.

I have replaced my old laptop screen as it had a crack, new laptop screen is FHD 1920 * 1080.

When I check under device manager -> monitors -> Generic PnP Monitor -> Events it is still showing the old display which was a BOE0672.

My new screen is a N156HGE-EA1.

I am running Intel UHD Graphics 620 and NVIDIA GeForce 940MX.

When I attempt to add a custom resolution, right click on desktop -> Intel graphic settings I get the error that the screen bandwidth has exceeded. This should not be the case as I am sure Graphics 620 is capable of well more than 1920*1080.

I have tried updating drivers for both monitor and display adapters both auto and manually restarted and still nothing.

Laptop is a Acer Aspire 5 A515-51G-51Z7 on Windows 10.

TIA.